# Best practice for writing specific exceptions

Tags: exception

What is considered best practice for writing custom exception classes? For example, if I'm creating a simple business application, should I create an exception for each domain object (CustomerNotFoundException, EmployeeNotFoundException, ProductNotFoundException, etc.)? If I do, it seems like a lot of clutter. In the examples in books that I'm studying, they always seem to have a 'not found' exception specifically for a domain object. But when I read discussions about exceptions, I get the sense that I shouldn't be creating a lot of custom exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really based on the situation. For example in an enterprise system where there's a lot of people working on the same enviroment and/or where it's expected that other might extend your code or build on it, it's is rather useful to have different exceptions, to provide a more detailed interface to your code. On small systems, with static codebase on the otherhand, it's rather cumbersome and just makes the code less transparent. In general as a rule of thumb your code should document itself and/or should have a detailed documentation (with preferably the source included) available, so others can find the source of the problem, regardless if you have custom excetions or not.